# Attacks on encrypted computer?

Tags: disk-encryption, bitlocker, dm-crypt

I think we all know the fact that boot-harddrives can be encrypted.
Windows usually uses Bitlocker (relying on AES-CBC) and Linux / Unix usually uses dm-crypt (relying on AES-CBC) and the rest of the software usually uses XTS-mode (TrueCrypt, BestCrypt,...).

Now, there's the potential for bitflip attacks with CBC.
My first thought was to use this for DoS, by simply flipping any bit of either the drive's salt or of the log-in hashs. **Would it be possible, by flipping a single bit (multiple bits), to deny access from any legitimate user?**
The computer can be considered shut-down as of time of acquiration.

**Are there any attacks, exploiting the bit-flipping property of CBC, to break the security of the targeted computer?**
A security break can be a DoS, a placement of an exploit or similar.

Comment: `My first thought was to use this for DoS, by simply flipping any bit of either the drive's salt or of the log-in hashs.` And how would you do that?

Comment: If you have enough privileged access to the hard drive that you can randomly flip bits, then couldn't you just flip *all* of the bits on the hard drive?

Comment: As I understanfld bit flipping attack applies if you can see the decrypted output. Thats how you can manage to obtain desired plaintext step by step). Take a look at evil maid attack. For doing a DoS, you can alter the key slot and data is lost..

Comment: @ρss, flipping a bit of the salt of the drive shouldn't be too hard. Flipping a bit of the password hashes means locating them, which is my question. If it wasn't clear yet, an attacker has access to the drive and can actually flip bits (maybe using some live-OS)

Comment: @Johnny, of course this would work and cause the requested DoS. But it would take hours to flip every single bit of a drive, as you'd have to read every bit and write every bit. I'm rather interested in a "surgical" / precise bit-flip, which can be executed within ~1 minute (1800 MB).

Comment: @r00t, so it is absolutely impossible to attack such drives without being able to see your own changes?

Comment: I meant that attacking with bit flipping requires to be able to see the output as far as i understand. Causing the DoS is easy as you can alter the key slot, the legit passphrase will be ununsable after that. You can attack such drives with bootkit like evil maid attack i mentionned.

Comment: @r00t, by "key slot", do you mean the unix pwd file / the windows registry password hash or do you mean the encryption program's salt for the key derivation to unlock the drive?

Comment: I mean with luks for example, your passphrase for unlocking the drive is derivated and the key obtained can decrypt the master key stored in a key slot. That schema allow you to have multiple passphrase at the same time able to unlock the drive. If you alter the encrypted master key (in their key slot) passphrase becomes unusable.

Comment: @r00t, thank your for your comments. I think you've answered my question enough. So could please post a fully qualified answer (including your above comments), so I can accept it?

Comment: You're welcome. Ok no problem give me five minutes ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand, bit flipping attack applies if you can see the decrypted output. Thats how you can manage to obtain desired plaintext changes step by step.

Look at the [Evil Maid attack](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2009/10/evil_maid_attac.html) if you want to see an example of full disk encryption defeat.

Causing the DoS is easy as you can alter the key slot (you can know where it's located easily), the legit passphrase will be unusable after that.

With LUKS, for example, your passphrase for unlocking the drive is derivated and the key obtained can decrypt the master key stored in a key slot. That scheme allows you to have multiple passphrases at the same time being able to unlock the drive (for multiple users without the need to share the passphrase) and to change the passphrase without the need to decrypt-encrypt all the disk again. If you alter the encrypted master key(s) (in their key slot) passphrase(s) become(s) unusable and indeed, the data is lost (DoS).

Comment: I've proposed an edit to your answer to improve your spelling a bit. I also added a link to the evil maid attack (using schneier's blog).